# repeat update record according to various values

Tags: php, for-loop, codeigniter, foreach

I'm new to Codigniter. I have a controller with update code according to a single variable (`$id`). I want to repeat the update command in the database according to various ID numbers. It does not work correctly except in the case of a single value. My code is:

```
        $id = (107708,112293,119622,126474,126551,126710,126711,126756,126796,126797);

        $data['id'] = strip_tags($id);

        $where = array('id'=>$id);

        $num = $this->data->get_data_where('sessions',$where,'id')->num_rows();

        $sessions = $this->data->get_data_where('sessions',$where,'id')->row();
        
        if($sessions->canceled != 1){

           $set['canceled'] = 1;

           $this->data->update_data('sessions', $set,$where);

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use forloop

```
for ($i = 0;$i < count($array_id);$i++){
    $this->data->update_data('sessions',$set, array('id'=>$array_id[$i]));
}
```